# Условие в UPDATE

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть два запроса:

```
UPDATE stationery_request t1
SET t1.price=4
WHERE t1.price is null

UPDATE stationery_request t1
SET t1.name='value'
WHERE t1.name is null
```

**Как можно обновить записи в `t1.price` если он `null` и `t1.name` если они не `null` независимо друг от друга, в одном запросе?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE stationery_request
SET
price = COALESCE(price,4),
name = COALESCE(name, 'value')
WHERE price is null OR name is null
```

Использую WHERE для того, чтобы хоть как-то уменьшить выборку.

[COALESCE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement/page2.html)

Comment: этот вариант больше нравится.

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете использовать вот такой подход:

```
UPDATE stationery_request t1
SET
t1.price = 
    CASE t1.price
    WHEN NULL THEN 4
    ELSE t1.price = t1.price
    END,
t1.name =
    CASE t1.name
    WHEN NULL THEN 'value'
    ELSE t1.name = t1.name
    END
```

Лучше не объединить. Но теперь задайте себе вопрос, а нужно ли? Чем вас не устраивают отдельные запросы?

Отдельные запросы даже быстрее будут, чем такая петрушка, если правильно расставить индексы.