# В зависимости от значения, поменять значения в другой ячейки

Tags: запрос, update, select, mysql

Мне нужно составить довольно не простой запрос к бд. Моя таблица (`table_bla`) выглядит так:

[image: Изображение]

На словах запрос звучит так:
Выбрать первое ненулевое значение во `float_val`, где `fiel_id 208,209,210` для этого `obj_id`. И если оно больше 1000, но меньше 2000, то в `rev_val` этого `obj_idб` где `field_id 402`, поставить 1.
Если выбранное значение больше 2000 но меньше 5000, то в `rev_val` этого `obj_idб` где `field_id 402`, поставить 2.
И больше 10000, но меньше 20000  - 4
остальное 402 = 5

Comment: Что значит "первое"? "Не нулевое" -- это NOT NULL или не равно нулю (таких я не видел на картинке). И вообще, для данной картинки показать бы, что и как должно получиться в результате.

И нафига картинка? mysql (в консоли), запрос с выводом на консоль, copy/paste текст в вопрос -- и всё. В linux'е в xterm'е -- мышом, в виндах -- выделить, в угловом меню выбрать copy, в браузере -- paste.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно тебе поможет мой [вопрос от февраля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/195211/mysql-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-update)

```
UPDATE stationery_request t1
SET
t1.price = 
    CASE t1.price
    WHEN NULL THEN 4
    ELSE t1.price = t1.price
    END
```