# Как обновить только некоторые значения строки в запросе? Выборочный UPDATE mysql

Tags: mysql, update, insert

Есть таблица contacts с полями:

```
a TINYTEXT NOT NULL
b TINYTEXT NOT NULL
c VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
d VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
```

Известны значения `a` и `b`, не известны значения `c` и `d` (они могут быть записаны в БД, а могут не быть записаны) для конкретной строки.

Задача: обновить известные значения `a` и `b` таким образом, чтобы не перезаписать (не удалить) неизвестные значения `c` и `d`.

Вариант решения через INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO `contacts` (`a`, `b`) 
VALUES (?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `a` = VALUES(`a`), `b` = VALUES(`b`)
```

имеет ограничение: должны быть заданы дефолтные значения полей `a` и `b`, чего нет в моем случае.

Насколько я понимаю, [COALESCE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement/page2.html) в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/195323/27377) к моему вопросу неприменима, поскольку у меня значения могут быть отличными от NULL и неизвестными. Или это не так?

Вопрос: можно ли обновить часть записей в строке, не трогая поля со значениями, неизвестными на момент обновления?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE contacts SET a = ?, b = ?;
```

Опционально можно добавить WHERE

Comment: что это даст? Обновить строку нужно независимо от того что в неизвестных полях.

Comment: Это обновит вам все строки независимо от того, что в неизвестных полях

Comment: Разобрался; действительно, UPDATE обновляет произвольное значение столбцов при необходимости, а не всю строку только.